# YouTube video: fit content on non 16:9 father (as background-size: cover)

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, youtube-api

Is there a way to simulate `object-fit: cover` or `background-size: cover` on a YouTube `iframe` or using the API?

Notice that the video's container is not a 16:9 proportional. It would be nice to have a solution or formula that can work for all the proportions.

Comment: Both CSS properties you mentioned are meant to "cover" the container's width and height with the excess width/height (whichever is left over) "hidden" outside the element. If you do this with a YouTube iframe the controls will be outside the viewable area also. Is this what you want, or did you want the iframe to fill the container?

Comment: There is no problem about the controls being hidden because the video is meant to be a background. User actually should not interact with it. And yes, I want the `cover` behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, hopefully my answer helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the source video is at least horizontal, this should work.

1. Check the height of the container
2. Calculate the aspect ratio of the video
3. Set the height of the iframe to be equal to the height of the container and set the width by multiplying the (reversed) aspect ratio to the container width.
4. Position the video absolutely within the container to make sure it's centered.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ilxhlnDo7_M" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px; /* whatever you want */
  width: 100%; /* whatever you want */
}

.container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const video = container.querySelector('iframe')
const videoAspectRatio = video.clientWidth / video.clientHeight

video.style.height = `${container.clientHeight}px`
video.style.width = `${container.clientWidth * videoAspectRatio}px`
```

Seems SO embeds don't support YouTube embedding so I've broken the example out into a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5bxpuzf/4/

An unfortunate drawback is the "flash of unstyled content" you'll get while the video resizes, I'd suggest fading the video in after it loads to avoid the FOUC.

Here's a fiddle with some different containers as examples. The video will be 100% height of the container and centered horizontally: https://jsfiddle.net/e5bxpuzf/2/

**NOTE:** I chose not to write a conditional to check if the video height is greater than the width because it seems like it'd be a fringe case. If you need, I can update the fiddle to accommodate.

Comment: I had to play with the aspect ratio a little bit, multiplying it by 1.4. That was the only change I made. Works great here, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.